# How can I populate a stream with a value from a future?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, reactive-programming

I'm using streams to monitor changes in my [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) backend. That works all right for updates, but I do not get the initial value.

```dart
class A {
  final Stream<DocumentSnapshot> _visitorCount =
      Firestore.instance.document('ServerData/serverStatus').snapshots();

  Stream<int> get visitorCount {
    return Observable(_visitorCount)
        .map((DocumentSnapshot doc) => doc['activeUsers'] as int);
  }
}
```

I could use `rxdart`'s `startWith` to provide an initial value, but reading out this value results in a `Future<int>` and I'd need to supply an `int` to `startWith`.

```dart
static Future<int> f = Firestore.instance
  .collection('ServerData')
  .document('serverStatus')
  .get()
  .then((doc) => doc['activeUsers'] as int);
```

down the road I use it like this:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
          stream: _visitorCount,
          initialData: 0,
          builder: (context, snapshot) =>
              Text('${snapshot.data} users logged in') ...
```

I provide `0` as initial value but this is of course just a temporary value.
I'm sure this is so obvious but still I struggle to get it right.
What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: and providing "0"  (or any other value) to startWith is not an option?

Comment: Weird, `document.snapshots()` should provide you the initial value once it's loaded, and possibly any updates after that. So if you don't update your `ServerData/serverStatus` then your `visitorCount` stream never emits anything?

Comment: what do you mean by `initial value` ?  There's no initial value in your code

Comment: I assumed `ServerData/serverStatus` already contains a document in firestore.

Comment: @Edman you are right the data is provided in the stream, but I missed it and thus I tried to re-fetch it somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the problem I needed to solve did not require me to add some value from a future into the stream to make up for missed values. All I needed is to use a `BehaviorSubject` as pointed out by Remi Rousselet.
But for completeness: here is how you take a value from a `Future` and push it into a stream:

### Inserting a value from a `Future` into a stream

```dart
class A {
  Subject<int> _stateSubject;
  Subject<int> _state;
  Subject<int> get state {
    return _state;
  }

  A() {
    _stateSubject = new BehaviorSubject();
    _state = _stateSubject;

    Firestore.instance
        .document('ServerData/serverStatus')
        .snapshots()
        .map((DocumentSnapshot doc) => doc['activeUsers'] as int)
        .listen((int value) {
      _stateSubject.add(value);
    });
  }

  Future<int> get visitorCount => Firestore.instance
      .document('ServerData/serverStatus')
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot d) => d.data['activeUsers']);
  void addFromFuture() => visitorCount.then((int v) => _state.add(v + 1));
}
```

By calling `addFromFuture` I can query some value that will result in a `Future<int>`, take this value and push it into the `Subject` with the `add()` function. All the listeners to the `_state`-`Subject` will receive those updates.

### Why is using a `BehaviorSubject` easier?

As an explanation why `BehaviorSubject` saves us from using this awkward workaround with `Future`s (taken from the [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) docs):

[image]

Even though another subscriber came in late, the most recent received item is buffered and delivered correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `BehaviorSubject` to provide initial value.

```
class A {
  Subject<String> _stateSubject;
  Stream<String> _state;
  Stream<String> get state {
    return _state;
  }

  A() {
    _stateSubject = new BehaviorSubject(seedValue: "initial value");
    _state = _stateSubject.asBroadcastStream();

    Stream fireStoreStream; // your firestore query here
    fireStoreStream.listen((value) {
      _stateSubject.add(value.toString()); // push your new value
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is I don't have the `seedValue` at initialization, it needs to be fetched separately. What am I missing? I tried it like [this](https://gist.github.com/marcmo/fbec8e580cac64f52a76ebaebc062c86) but don't get the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "the result" ?

Comment: I mean I create the stream and when it's updated, I get the updated value. But I do not get the initial value from the database.

Comment: thanks @rémi-rousselet for making me aware of `BehaviorSubjects`. I could make my example work with this rx feature "A special StreamController that captures the latest item that has been added to the controller, and emits that as the first item to any new listener." I upvoted your reply but would just not mark it as the solution to my question which was how to re-fetch the missed event with a `Future` and stick it into the existing stream.

Comment: I'll admit I still don't understand the problem. As I've done the following many times (including pagination and all) using that logic without problem. Maybe there's an information specific to your use case you omitted?

Comment: don't get me wrong...your approach with the BehaviorSubject DID work!

Comment: for the seedValue the syntax has changed to `BehaviorSubject.seeded("initial value")`

Answer (score 0):

Firestore needs time to load the data before you can have something useful emitted to your StreamBuilder. The `hasData` property of the various snapshots can be used to react to this state at build time.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _visitorCount,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Loading..
    // Here the data is loaded and available
  },
)
```